# How Can I initialize a column within a Parse.com class as Number Type with Value = 0?

Tags: python, json, parse-platform, cloud

I want to build a counter for my users - and it would be nice to be able to provide an initial value for a new column. Is this possible?

Of course, it would also be nice to set that value to zero when a new row is created within the class as well. I imagine this second part is dead simple with "cloud code", but I'm not sure where to start.

Here's where I'm at. I can get the first 100 users (or set a param and get a thousand users) in python:

```
import json,httplib,urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
#params = urllib.urlencode({"where":json.dumps({
#       "limit": "1000"
#     })})
params = ''
connection.connect()
connection.request('GET', '/1/classes/user?%s' % params, '', {
      "X-Parse-Application-Id": "APPLICATION_ID",
       "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "RESTKEY"
     })
result = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())

print len(result['results'])
```

and then I would loop over them and POST a zero value for each user.

How many users can I retrieve at a time? 
Also - Can I ask parse for a count of the elements in a given class?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot count the total number of the objects in a class if it has over 1000 objects, in one query request. You need to use `skip` and `limit` query constraint to fetch you data page by page (each page or query returns max limit of 1000 records) You set the `limit` always to 1000 and for each query request, you add 1000 to your skip value. That way you can go over all your data in 1000 object steps. This way you can go all over your data, set values or count the total number.

Read more: https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide#queries-query-constraints

Comment: Thanks -- can you point me to a resource that will help with adding a cloud hook to initialize the values to zero if a new row (ie - user) is added?

Comment: If you want to set a value in a column to zero for a new row, you can do that in the `beforeSave` trigger for that class. Simply test if the object is being created with `request.object.isNew()` and then set that value you want to zero like `request.object.set("column", value);`

Comment: Awesome. So the hook request.object.isNew() will fire each time a new row is created?

Comment: In a beforeSave trigger for a Class, `request.object.isNew()` returns a boolean which if it is true it means that a new row is about to be created. Forget the old archived forum questions, Parse has a separate guide on how to write Cloud Code: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers